# Trying to update working repo to HEAD revision: Unable to create file [Folder] \ [file].py: No such file or directory?

Tags: git, gitlab, pull, git-reset

I try to do

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

and get the following error:

```
error: unable to create file [Folder] /.gitkeep: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file [Folder] /[Filename].py: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file [Folder] /[Filename].py: No such file or directory
error: unable to create file [Folder] /[Filename].py: No such file or directory
```

I've tried pulling, stashing, and even downloading the files directly from gitlab, unzipping them, and putting them into the folder. Nothing works.

Comment: What is the actual directory (folder) name? What OS are you using? Does your OS restrict directory names? Is the actual name, as encoded in the Git commit, forbidden by your OS?

Comment: Danish AIS, Windows 10. Other questions along the same lines seem to say that certain characters are not allowed but all file and folder names are short and only contain alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Hm, seems like it should work then. Is there a file of that name in the way?

Comment: Nope. I've deleted all other files in that folder as well as put the files in that folder to "create" them myself, hoping it would recognize them or something.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to debug this on Windows. On a Linux or Unix system I'd run a system-call tracer to see precisely what strings Git is passing to the OS...

Comment: Okay, I'll look into doing that tomorrow. Thanks for the help.